# Где ставить ударение в "новорожденный"

Tags: ударения

Где ставить ударение в слове "новорожденный"?

Answer (score 1):

НОВОРОЖДЁННЫЙ; (разг.) НОВОР**О**ЖДЕННЫЙ,

Answer (score 0):

В словах с буквой Ё ударение всегда ставится именно на этот звук :)

Comment: А если нет уверенности, что там Ё, а не Е?

Answer (score 0):

Нормативно - новорожд**ё**нный. Это никто не оспаривает.
Некоторыми словарями вариант новор**о**жденный действительно фиксируется как разговорный, но я бы не спешил принимать его таковым. Пока что скорее просторечное.

К слову сказать, с роженицей дело ещё хуже. Словари фиксируют три варианта ударения, из которых даже совершенно дикое ?"р**о**женица" называют разговорным или диалектным. А доморощенные филологи как в последний бой идут выяснять, какое из двух оставшихся нормативных (рож**е**ница и рожен**и**ца) нормативнее другого.

Про р**о**ды и род**ы** даже говорить не хочется. Полная каша в некоторых головах...